# Using React-pdf/renderer and Image rotates my image

Tags: renderer, react-pdf

I'm created a PDF file using react-pdf/renderer. Everything is working great, but my image is sideways. When using an img tag it is shown correctly. I've tried searching and I find thoughts like onLoadSuccess check the rotate property? But I don't know how to do that using this library.

Here is my code:

```
<Document>
   <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            alignContent: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            padding: "10pt",
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            color: "white",
            fontSize: "20pt",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            margin: 0,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{textAlign: "center", marginBottom: "5pt"}}>
            Profile stuff here
          </Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize: "14pt", textAlign: "center"}}>
            More profile stuff
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            margin: "40pt",
            alignSelf: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
          }}
        >
          {report?.image && (
            <Image
              style={{
                alignSelf: "center",
                margin: "5pt",
                maxWidth: "400pt",
                maxHeight: "400pt",
                width: "auto",
                height: "auto",
                border: 1,
              }}
              src={report.image}
            />
          )}
        </View>
    </View>
  </Page>
</Document>
```

The image comes from Firebase and is correctly displayed when I look at it there. I think it has something to do with the image taken in landscape or portrait mode, but then I am lost.

Thank you for any advice.